# Show that simple bipartite graph with n vertices doesn't have more than $\frac{n^2}4$ edges.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am stuck at finding the solution because the lack understanding of bipartite graph theory. 
Bipartite graph is defined as a graph which can be separated into two sets of vertices such as that each vertices in one set has edges connecting the vertices in the another set.

Please, could you show me an answer for the question.

Comment: Even your definition of bipartite graph is incorrect. Check your textbook please.

Comment: I am sorry for my bad English. The literature is not in English, so I need to translate it first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a bipartite graph your $n$ vertices can be partitioned into two subsets of size $i$ and $(n-i)$, $0 \leq i \leq n$, and you can only have edges between vertices of different subsets, so you have a maximum of $i(n-i)$ edges if every member of one subset is connected to every member of the other subset.

$f(i) = i(n-i), 0 \leq i \leq n$ is maximized by $i = \frac{n}{2}$ which leads to $\frac{n}{2} \frac{n}{2} = \frac{n^2}{4}$ being the maximum number of edges.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) I am understand right now

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

A bipartite graph is divided into two pieces, say of size $p$ and $q$, where $p+q=n$. Then the maximum number of edges is $pq$.

Using calculus, we can deduce that this product is maximal when $p=q$, in which case it is equal to $n^2/4$.

Comment: To show that the product $pq$ is maximal when $p=q$ does not require calculus. Just use $4pq=(p+q)^2-(p-q)^2=n^2-(p-q)^2$. And divide by $4$ to get the required result directly.

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes, I know that. It struck me, so I wrote it..

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a graph $G$ is partitioned into two disjoint subsets $U$ and $V$ then $G$ is bipartite if every edge connects a vertex in $U$ to a vertex in $V$. Therefore, for each vertex in $U$ there are at most $|V|$ many possible edges origininating from it . So we have $|U||V|$ possible edges in the whole graph at most. Now with the constraint  that $|U|+|V|=n$ we maximize $|U||V|$ and this is indeed the case when $|U|=|V|=\frac{n}{2}$ that is we have at most $|U||V|=\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges.